# Importing a transpiled package for unit testing

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript package that is shipped transpiled to JS with rollup. The package uses `type: module` and rollup produces the following files:

```
dist/cjs/index.cjs
dist/es6/index.mjs
dist/browser/index.js
dist/types.d.ts
```

My unit testing is also in TypeScript so that I can test the typings. I use mocha with all the special configuration:

```json
{
  "spec": "test/*.test.@(cjs|mjs|ts)",
  "require": [
    "ts-node/register"
  ],
  "loader": "ts-node/esm"
}
```

The problem is that I cannot easily import this package from the unit testing. I cannot import `'..'` or use `tsconfig-paths` since `type: module` disallows directory imports. If I import `../dist/cjs/index.cjs` I lose the typings. Does anyone see any way I could import the compiled package with the typings?

Currently the only solution is to drop `type: module` and use `import from '..'` - which means I am going back 5 years.

The package is https://github.com/mmomtchev/query-mvt if anyone is interested. I have currently dropped `type: module`.

Comment: Why are you unit testing the result of `dist`? You can trust that rollup knows what it's doing, and your unit tests should import directly from the source files that you yourself write.

Comment: Because I am injecting `fetch` from `node-fetch` when rolling up for Node.js